# Data loss while Deferencing void* to float

Tags: c++, multithreading, void-pointers

I have made 2 threads and calculating the value of PI using the thread function. I am trying to return the value from thread function into the main (to calculate PI as example shows), but its not giving me correct answer. Whenever I run it, the thread function's cout statement gives correct answer, but I am not getting the same while dereferencing the void* operator. Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

class ThreadObj 
{
public:
int n;
float flag;
};

void* Func(void* param)
{
    float num, den,partialN;
    float partialSum = 0;

    ThreadObj* obj1 = (ThreadObj*)param;


    num = obj1->flag;
    partialN = obj1->n;

    for ( int i=0; i<partialN; i++)
    {

    if(num==1)
    {
    den = 4*i + 1;

    }
    else
    {
    den = 4*i+3;
    }
    partialSum = partialSum + (num/den);
    }

cout<<"Answer of Thread's execution is: "<<partialSum<<endl;

//Returning the answer and casting it into appropriate datatype (void*)

void* ReturnPointer;

ReturnPointer = &partialSum;

return ReturnPointer;

//return (void*) partialSum;
//return partialSum;
}

int main()
{
float n;
float sum=0;

cout<< "Enter number of iteration: "<<endl;
cin>> n;

pthread_t Thread1, Thread2;
//Use 1st Thread to calculate the +ve terms

ThreadObj obj1;

obj1.n = n/2;
obj1.flag = 1.0;

pthread_create(&Thread1,NULL,&Func, &obj1); 

//Use 2nd Thread to calculate the -ve terms


ThreadObj obj2;

obj2.n = n/2;
obj2.flag = -1.0;

pthread_create(&Thread2,NULL,&Func, &obj2);

//Getting value from both threads

float PartialSum1=0, PartialSum2=0;

void* p1 = &PartialSum1;
void* p2 = &PartialSum2;

//pthread_join(Thread1,NULL);
pthread_join(Thread2, (void**) p1);
pthread_join(Thread1, (void**) p2);

cout<<endl<<"Partial Sum2 is: "<<PartialSum2<<endl;
cout<<endl<<"Partial Sum1 is: "<<PartialSum1<<endl;

sum = PartialSum1 + PartialSum2;

sum = sum * 4;
cout<< "Value of PI: "<<sum;
cout<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Sample output is:

Enter number of iteration: 
100

Answer of Thread's execution is: -1.25072
Answer of Thread's execution is: 2.03362

Partial Sum2 is: -1.12921e-05

Partial Sum1 is: -5.64419e-06
Value of PI: -6.77452e-05

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to a local variable that goes out of scope at the end of the function.  This is undefined behavior and you getting garbage is a result of that.

I would suggest that instead of returning a `void*` you should pass in another parameter to the function and put the result in that.

Comment: Thanks! I personally also think the same. I was just trying to use pthread_join return method. So we can't use it by this pthread_join method (which takes return as pointer)?

Comment: @TalhaIrfan You might be able to if you dynamically allocate the memory with `new`.  You would need to remember to `delete` it when you are done with it in `main`.  I don't have much experience with p_thread.  If you have access to C++11 I would suggest you look into [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)

Comment: I have tried to avoid local variable as pointer (as you can see in my code, I tried to return the partialSum directly), but it gives me error like this: Invalid cast from type float to type void* in return (void*) partialSum;